# Hide content when click on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I have 4 navigation links (see below) with ID= activator which shows content, boxclose closes content.

I'm able to click all activators and open all content while it needs to open only one and close the other(s).

See here the script I use:
(werkwijze is custom, i also have the same code with other names like -contact)

```
$(function() {
        $('#activator-werkwijze').click(function(){
            $('#overlay-werkwijze').fadeIn('fast',function(){
                $('#box-werkwijze').animate({'bottom':'0px'},800);
            });
        });
        $('#boxclose-werkwijze').click(function(){
            $('#box-werkwijze').animate({'bottom':'-600px'},800,function(){
                $('#overlay-werkwijze').fadeOut('fast');
            });
        });
    });


<a id="activator-bureau" class="activator">bureau</a>
<a id="activator-werkwijze" class="activator">werkwijze</a>
<a id="activator-klanten" class="activator">klanten</a>
<a id="activator-contact" class="activator">contact</a>
```

This is the script which works, (the overlay is useless) jsfiddle.net/8y7Sr/126/

Comment: Just a general remark - why do you fadeIn(), and after the fadeIn() animate the box in? And after animating the div out, fading it out?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a data attribute on the activator links, and use that as a selector:

```
<a id="activator-bureau" class="activator" data-target="box-bureau">bureau</a>
<a id="activator-werkwijze" class="activator" data-target="box-werkwijze">werkwijze</a>
<a id="activator-klanten" class="activator" data-target="box-klanten">klanten</a>
<a id="activator-contact" class="activator" data-target="box-contact">contact</a>

<div id="box-contact" class="activatee">Something</div>
Etc.

$(function() {
    $(".activator").click(function(e) {
        var $target = $(e.target).data("target");
        $(".activatee").not("#" + $target).fadeOut('fast');
        $target.fadeIn() // or whatever your animation is
        Etc.
    })
})
```